# How to use context manager with lists

Tags: python

I have a class, that has initialisation and cleaning logic:

```
class Bird(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __enter__(self):
        print("enter " + self.name)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        print("exit " + self.name)
```

I use it with context manager:

```
with Bird("chicken") as b:
    print(b)
```

But now I want use list of my objects with same behaviour, ie after working with list, its objects should be disposed:

```
with DisposableList([Bird("A"), Bird("B")]) as list:
    #some ops
```

How I can implement list or maybe another solution?

Comment: _"its objects should be disposed"_ Meaning what? Their `__exit__` method should be called? Also, you clearly know how to write context managers, so what's preventing you from writing a `DisposableList` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to implememt my own list and seems like it works.

```
class DisposableList(list):

    def __enter__(self):
        print("enter list")
        for v in self:
            v.__enter__()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *exc):
        print("exit list")
        for v in self:
            v.__exit__()


class Bird(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __enter__(self):
        print("enter " + self.name)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *exc):
        print("exit " + self.name)


with DisposableList([Bird("A"), Bird("B")]) as ctx:
    print(ctx)
```

Output:

```
enter list
enter A
enter B
[<__main__.Bird object at 0x7f9186151668>, <__main__.Bird object at 0x7f9186151780>]
exit list
exit A
exit B
```

Any notes are welcome!

Comment: I would avoid `list` as a variable name.

Comment: Need to pass *exc to v.__exit__(), no?

Answer (score 4):

if you don't need a class

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
@contextmanager
def bird(lst):
    print 'enter {}'.format(lst)
    yield lst
    print 'exit {}'.format(lst)


with bird([1,2,3,4]) as f:
    print f


enter [1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
exit [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap a loop around it:

```
for bi in ['hawk','chicken','eagle']:
    with Bird(bi) as b:
        print(b)
```

Or, perhaps better still, use a generator to loop over each instance of a Bird object in turn:

```
def bird_gen(li):
    for bird in li:
        with Bird(bird) as b:
            yield b

for b in bird_gen(['hawk','chicken','eagle']):
    print(b)
```

Comment: simple but ... yeah, no _but_. just simple!

Answer (score 0):

You can still pass a list of `Bird` objects by creating a `__repr__` for each `Bird` class:

```
class Bird(object):
   def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
   def __enter__(self):
     print("enter " + str(self.name))
     return self
   def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
     print("exit " + str(self.name))
   def __repr__(self):
     return '{}({})'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self.name)

with Bird([Bird("A"), Bird("B")]) as f:
  print(f)

print('-'*10)
with Bird('chicken') as f:
  print(f)
```

Output:

```
enter [Bird(A), Bird(B)]
Bird([Bird(A), Bird(B)])
exit [Bird(A), Bird(B)]
----------
enter chicken
Bird(chicken)
exit chicken
```